# PHPのお問い合わせフォームがさくらサーバーだと動くがロリポップだと動かない

Tags: php

さくらサーバーから
ロリポップへ移行を検討しているのですが
PHPで作ったお問い合わせフォームがロリポップだと動作しません。
**具体的にはsubmit.phpファイルのif文のelse、すなわち

”1メールの送信に失敗しました。
大変お手数ですが、もう一度やり直して下さい。”と表示が出ます。**

以下がコードなのですが
３種類のファイルを作り、
submit.phpファイルの中にある

****「さくらサーバーでのメールアドレス」（info@〇〇.sakura.ne.jp）****

という箇所を
ロリポップでのアドレス（info@〇〇.weblike.jp）に変更すれば動くものと
思っていたのですが、それだけでは動きませんでした。

ロリポップへ問い合わせても
原因がわからないとのことで、コードの問題なのか
ロリポップのPHP側の設定なのかわからないでいます。

どなたか似たような事例で問題解決した方が
いればアドバイスいただけますと助かります。

**submit.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', "On");
// var_dump($_POST);

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $furigana = $_POST['furigana'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $otoiawase = $_POST['otoiawase'];

    //メールの内容
    $body .= "お問い合わせいただきましてありがとうございます。下記の情報を受け取りました。\nこちらから折り返しご連絡させていただきます。\n\n";
    $body .= "お名前:".$name."\n";
    $body .= "フリガナ:".$furigana."\n";
    $body .= "メールアドレス:".$address."\n";
    $body .= "電話番号:".$tel."\n";
    $body .= "お問い合わせ内容:\n".$otoiawase."\n\n";
    $body .= "▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼\n";
    $body .= "【Web担当者の作り方】\n";
    $body .= "メール:example@example.com\n";
    $body .= "URL:https://www.web-officer.com/\n";
    $body .= "▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼△▼\n";

    //メールの送り先,メールの送り元,メールタイトル
    $flg = bSENDMAIL3($address,"さくらサーバーでのメールアドレス","【Web担当者の作り方】です。お問い合わせいただきましてありがとうございます！",$body);

    if($flg == true) {
        // $massage .= "1メールの送信が完了しました。<br />お問い合わせいただきましてありがとうございました！";
        $flg = bSENDMAIL3("自分のプライベートのEmailアドレス","さくらサーバーでのメールアドレス","【Web担当者の作り方】です。お問い合わせいただきましてありがとうございます！",$body);
        if($flg == true) {
            $massage .= "2メールの送信が完了しました。<br />お問い合わせいただきましてありがとうございました！";
        } else {
            $massage .= "2メールの送信に失敗しました。<br />大変お手数ですが、もう一度やり直して下さい。";
        }
    } else {
        $massage .= $address."1メールの送信に失敗しました。<br />大変お手数ですが、もう一度やり直して下さい。";
    }



}


function bSENDMAIL3($to,$from,$sub,$body) {
    mb_language("ja");
    mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");//utf-8 or SJIS
    $Head="";
    $Head.="From: ".$from."\n";
    $Head.="Mime-Version: 1.0\n";
    $Head.="Reply-To: ".$from."\n";
    $Head.="X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    $flg = mb_send_mail($to, $sub, $body,$Head);
    return $flg;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>送信完了画面 | お問い合わせフォームの作り方</title>
</head>

<body>

<?=$massage?>

</body>
</html>
```

**confirmation.php**

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$furigana = $_POST['furigana'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$otoiawase = $_POST['otoiawase'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>確認画面 | お問い合わせフォームの作り方</title>
<style type="text/css">
input[readonly] {
    background-color: #CCC;
}

.gray_bg {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<form action="submit.php" method="post" name="myform">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>お名前</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" readonly="readonly" value="<?=$name?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>フリガナ</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="furigana" readonly="readonly" value="<?=$furigana?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>メールアドレス</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="address" readonly="readonly" value="<?=$address?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>電話番号</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="tel" readonly="readonly" value="<?=$tel?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>お問い合わせ内容</td>
    <td><textarea name="otoiawase" class="gray_bg" readonly><?=$otoiawase?></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="送信する" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**contact.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>お問い合わせフォームの作り方</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_contactform() {
    var name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
    var furigana = $('input[name="furigana"]').val();
    var address = $('input[name="address"]').val();
    var tel = $('input[name="tel"]').val();
    var otoiawase = $('textarea[name="otoiawase"]').val();
    var errmsg = "";
    if(name == "") {
        errmsg = "お名前を入力して下さい\n";
    }
    if(furigana == "") {
        errmsg = errmsg + "フリガナを入力して下さい\n";
    }
    if(address == "") {
        errmsg = errmsg + "メールアドレスを入力して下さい\n";
    }
    if(!address.match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/)) {
        errmsg = errmsg + "メールアドレスをご確認下さい\n";
    }
    if(tel == "") {
        errmsg = errmsg + "電話番号を入力して下さい\n";
    }
    if(otoiawase == "") {
        errmsg = errmsg + "お問い合わせ内容を入力して下さい\n";
    }
    if(errmsg != "") {
        alert(errmsg);
        return false;
    }
    $('form[name="myform"]').submit();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="confirmation.php" method="post" name="myform">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>お名前</td>
    <td ><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>フリガナ</td>
    <td ><input type="text" name="furigana" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>メールアドレス</td>
    <td ><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>電話番号</td>
    <td ><input type="text" name="tel" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>お問い合わせ内容</td>
    <td ><textarea name="otoiawase"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="確認画面へ" onclick="check_contactform()" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 問題解決のために、bSENDMAIL3を利用せず純粋にmb_send_mailを利用してメール送信テストを実行するスクリプトを実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: また環境の違いを比較するためにphpinfo等で違いがあるところがあればその情報もあるといいかも

Comment: 問題が起きているのは sendmail の送信周りなので、「問い合わせフォームが動かない」ではなく範囲を絞った質問を組み立てると回答もつきやすくなると思います。 / ヘルプの [再現可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) も参照してみてください。

Comment: `$flg = bSENDMAIL3(...)` の直後に `print_r(error_get_last());` を挿入するとエラーに関する情報が取れるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。PHPの設定は同じにして試してみました。
すると
Notice: Undefined variable: body in /home/users/2/ooooo/web/contact_form/submit.php on line 13
Notice: Undefined variable: massage in /home/users/2/ooooo/web/contact_form/submit.php on line 39

とエラーの確認ができました。（mb_send_mailも同じでした。）body, massage変数が未定義とのことですがsubmit.phpの中で定義はしているのですが何かコードの書き方に問題があるのでしょうか？

Comment: `$body`や`$massage`変数を初期化しないで `.=` 演算子を使用しているためかと思います。これは推測になりますが、さくらサーバーでは PHP7 よりも前のバージョンが提供されていて、ロリポップでは PHP7 以降のものがインストールされているのではないでしょうか。PHP7 以降では未定義変数との文字列結合はエラーになります。ただ、これが今回のエラーの原因である確証はありませんが。。。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに初期化するとエラーの表記なくなりました。
ですがいまだにメールの送信はうまくいかないですね。。。
ちなみにさくら、ロリポップともにPHP7.4CGI版でした。